# How do i make the total of my calculation app only be the right amount of digits for dollars and cents $0.00

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have this calculation formula which calculates the total after the user inputs all the neccisary fields however the total ends up being in 15+ digits instead of four i just want ther to be enoghe digits for dollars and cents 0.00

```
this.state = {
soldPrice: 0.0,
shippingCost: 0.0,
shippingCharge: 0.0,
itemCost: 0.0,
Profit: ' ',
paypalFee: 0.30,
paypalFeePercentage: 0.029,
ebayFee: 0.1,
profitMargin: '',
paypalFeeTotal: '',
ebayFeeTotal: '',
profitColor: '',
};
}

calculateProfit = () => {
const finalValue = parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) +
parseFloat(this.state.shippingCharge || 0) - parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) *
parseFloat(this.state.paypalFeePercentage || 0) - parseFloat(this.state.paypalFee  || 0)
 - parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) *
parseFloat(this.state.ebayFee || 0) - parseFloat(this.state.shippingCost || 0)
 - parseFloat(this.state.itemCost || 0);

this.setState({ finalValue });
}
<NumberInput
     onchange={(shippingCharge) => this.setState({ shippingCharge })}
     />
     </View>
<Text style={styles.profitResult}>
      TOTAL PROFIT:{this.state.finalValue}</Text>
      </View>
```

i tried using toPrecision but i'm not sure how to apply it to state without getting an error

Comment: Unrelated, but please consider indenting your code and using some reasonable indentation--it'll make everyone's life easier.

Comment: are you reffering to the calculate profit function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Number.toFixed()` with a decimal precision (2 in your case)

https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/

Also, since everything is already a float in your state, I don't believe you have to `parseFloat` everything with the `|| 0` for everything.

Comment: where in my component should i use it

Comment: Ex: `finalValue.toFixed(2)`

Comment: I'm getting this error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.finalValue.toFixed')

Comment: finalValue is not in your state but is the variable in your function...

Comment: i tried putting it here but its givining me an error const finalValue.toFixed(2) = parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0)

Comment: where are you exactly should i put it

Comment: SyntaxError: C:\Users\arich\Documents\efees\App.js: Unexpected token (33:16)

  31 |
  32 | calculateProfit = () => {
> 33 | const finalValue.toFixed(2) = parseFloat(this.state.soldPrice || 0) +

Comment: this.setState({ finalValue: finalValue.toFixed(2) }):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197899/discussion-between-prog-and-sunny-pelletier).